# How to inherit multiple functions and implementations C#

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a project I am working on and have different objects that can be "owners" of different other resources. Since these different owners can own different combinations of these items I thought it would be helpful to define the ownership part as an inheritable class or interface so an ownership can essentially be easily added by adding a subclass. I run into issues when I try to add more than one ownership (subclass) to an object. The difficult part comes in the form of the implementations that I want to have inherited. If it were simply member variables interfaces would easily solve this.

For example `Owner` and an resource (or list of resources) `A` and `B` that they can own.

```
public class A 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
(Obviously A and B are very different classes in reality but for example)

public interface IAOwner
{
    public List<A> AList { get; set; }

    public A GetA(string name) <possibly default implementation here?>;
}

public interface IBOwner
{
    public List<B> BList { get; set; }

    public B GetB(string name) <possibly default implementation here?>;
}

public class Owner : (some subclassing that includes IAOwner and IBOwner)
{
    <Some Owner-specific code here>
}

<Maybe some other type of owner that only owns "A" so only needs IAOwner>
```

A basic interface would work but then I would have to reimplement the functions each time.

My thought was to create the "ownership" interfaces with default implementations but those default implementations are not accessible without downcasting the object (Why C# requires that makes no sense to me, and not requiring it would fix this issue). My thoughts then were to create a base class for each combination of ownership (yes I could just put `ABOwner` on `Owner` directly but there are multiple types that are `ABOwner`s) but then I have to reimplement the functions and downcast `this` to call the base version which doesn't seem ideal to me.

```
public abstract class ABOwner : IAOwner, IBOwner
{
    public string GetA(string name) { return (this as IAOwner).GetA(name); }
    public string GetB(string name) { return (this as IBOwner).GetB(name); }
}

public class Owner : ABOwner {}
```

Is there any easier way to go about this? I Guess the problem revolves around interface default implementations not being available without downcasting, and I COULD do the method above to solve that but I feel like there should be a better way to go about it.

Comment: Have you considered writing extension methods?

Comment: Now that I am thinking about it I could just create a AList class and put all the functions on that. I still prefer the subclassing method as I can pass `Owner` into a function that needs IAOwner rather than passing in a AList and having it as a class allows me to link it to the resource easier. But I guess thats a possibility

Comment: @JimMischel I honestly didn't even know about those... Looks like they should work Ill try them here in a sec

Comment: @JimMischel Yep, those work exactly as I wanted. Thank you, I honestly had no clue you could do that.

Comment: It's kind of confusing what you are ultimately trying to achieve here with classes A and B since they are so simplified, but it seems like you may also benefit from using a generic base class or generic interface like `IOwner<T>` or `Owner<T>`, then your implementations could use something like `IOwner<A>` or `Owner<A>`

Comment: @TJRockefeller Fair I did simplify them probably too much. I don't think that would work though as `IOwner<T>` leaves me with the issue that A and B are not similar enough in the right aspects to warrant that and again I would be missing the implementations that need to be different between `IAOwner` and `IBOwner`, and multiple base class inheritance isnt allowed so `Owner<T>` would leave me stuck with one owner type. The extension methods Jim mentioned above worked perfectly though.

Comment: Actually `Owner<T>` would work for the multiple, but I would still be missing implementations